What’s the formula for the amount of runes required for a level up?
What’s the formula for the amount of runes required to level up in Elden Ring? Assuming there is one? I assume it’s some kind of percentage increase?

According to Fextralife:


The amount of Runes required to level up is calculated using the following formulas:

x = ((Lvl+81)-92)*0.02

x cannot be below 0, so change it to 0 if the formula resolves to below 0


Rune Cost = ((x+0.1)*((Lvl+81)^2))+1
The resulting number is always rounded down




